# Need help understanding what this C code does

Tags: c

I need help understanding what the following code is.

```
1 const char* (*srslte_rf_devname)(void* h);

2 int (*srslte_rf_start_rx_stream)(void* h, bool now);

3 int (*srslte_rf_stop_rx_stream)(void* h);

4 void (*srslte_rf_flush_buffer)(void* h);
```

What I think is happening on line 1 is that the const char* is a pointer that is a constant array of characters and it points to a pointer function called srslte_rf_devname and I dont know what the (void* h) is or what it is doing.

I think line 2 is declaring a pointer function with the name srslte_rf_start_rx_stream and the type is int. I don't know what the (void* h, bool now); is or what it is doing.

I think line 4 is declaring a pointer function with no return value "void" not sure what "type" the function is compared to the other lines.

Please help me to understand what the * means what the (*"some_stuff") means or point me to a resource that explains it.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) then the  [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft C standard. You have **pointers to functions.**

Comment: All four lines declare pointers to functions. The functions have different return types, and different arguments. The argument that they have in common (`void* h`) is a handle (i.e. pointer to an opaque type). You typically get the handle from an initialization function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. `const char* (*srslte_rf_devname)(void *h);`

Note that in the C grammar, `const char` is part of the *declaration-specifiers*, and `*` is part of the *declarator*. So, to understand this grammatically, we should group `*` with the rest of the declarator, not with the specifiers: `const char *(*srslte_rf_devname)(void *h)`.

Then, what this means is:

- `*(*srslte_rf_devname)(void *h)` is a `const char`.
- Therefore `(*srslte_rf_devname)(void *h)` is a pointer to `const char`.
- Therefore `(*srslte_rf_devname)` is a function taking `void *` and returning a pointer to `const char`.
- Therefore `srslte_rf_devname` is a pointer to a function taking `void *` and returning a pointer to `const char`.

After the above, it is easier to see the remaining items:

- `int (*srslte_rf_start_rx_stream)(void *h, bool now);` says `srslte_rf_start_rx_stream` is a pointer to a function taking `void *` and `bool` and returning an `int`.
- `int (*srslte_rf_stop_rx_stream)(void *h);` says `srslte_rf_stop_rx_stream` is a pointer to a function taking `void *` and returning an `int`.
- `void (*srslte_rf_flush_buffer)(void *h);` says `srslte_rf_flush_buffer` is a function taking `void *` and returning `void` (nothing).

Comment: For consistency: `const char *(*srslte_rf_devname)(void* h)` -> `const char *(*srslte_rf_devname)(void *h)`